# Checkboxsize relative to zoomed page

Tags: css, checkbox, scale

I know I can scale a checkbox this way:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
      transform:scale(1.5);
```

That way the checkbox keeps it's size, even when I zoom a page.

How can I tell it, that it is supposed to grow or shrink with the rest of the page?

I tried % and em, but that didn't work.

Comment: Did you try `vw` and `vh` ?

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't look reliable. Look at the issues here:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

What is your experience with ist?

Comment: Anyway, I tried it in Firefox this way:
  input[type=checkbox] {
    transform:scale(vh2, vw2);
  }
and it did't change a bit.

Comment: You can just set the `width` and `height` in `viewport units`, not using transform. Also try to set `minimum and maximum height/width`, because so they won't get too small or too big.
I'm not aware of another way to change the size of the checkboxes depending on the window size, except javascript.

Comment: Thank you Dennis,
would you be so kind to give me an example for my checkbox problem?